# starting web service

Tags: java, web-services

I created the service server using dynamic web project with bottom up approach (eclipse indigo and axis2). Right now, there's only one class (MyService.java) containing one public method:

```
public String doIt(){  
    return "abc";  
}
```

1. how do I create the web-based client? do I make a separate project? if so, what's the type of the project? maven, javaEE, dynamic web?
2. the soap request will contain an xml that will be most likely to later be parsed into a Java object. I assume that the POJO definition will be in the web service server project?
3. what's the naming convention for the classes and packages in web service project (both the server and client project)?
   thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1:**

You can create a new project the type will be maven, Java EE, dynamic Web even you can add a new module in your existing maven project also. if you wish to create a console based application you can create also.

**point 2:**

Yes, POJO definition will be in the web service.

**point 3:**

You just need to follow the Java standard naming conventions read [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)